# Color tinting an UIImage

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimage

I'm really stuck on tinting an UIImage with a certain tint. The UIImage is in a custom TableView cell (if that makes any difference).

[image]

Looking at the picture, the UIImage has been replaced by 0.5 opacity yellow and the original image has been discarded. I want a tint on an existing image, not overwrite the image entirely. (p.s: the numbers in the picture are labels that are on top of the image, they are unrelated).

I realize there are similiar threads on stackoverflow and I must have tried out all the code that there is :-) Nothing is working. I don't expect anyone to post any code, just a push in the right direction!

Explanation of the code below:

1. myImage is the image
2. color is the color, probably yellow, with an opacity of 0.5
3. I use [util tintedImageWithColor] with both *myImage* and *color*.
4. It comes out as the picture above.

Does anyone have an idea, a push in the right direction?

**Updated**

**MasterViewController.m**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ArticleCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Article *article = self.articles[indexPath.row];
    Utils *util = [[Utils alloc] init];

    // Populate cell components
    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithData:article.post_image_thumbnail_data];

    // Set image tint
    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:(160/15.0) green:(97/15.0) blue:(5/55.0) alpha:0.5];
     myImage = [util tintedImageWithColor:(UIImage *) myImage:(UIColor *) color blendingMode:kCGBlendModeDestinationIn highQuality:YES];

    cell.imageView.image = myImage;

    return cell;
}
```

**Utils.m**

```
- (UIImage *)tintedImageWithColor:(UIImage*)image : (UIColor *)tintColor blendingMode:(CGBlendMode)blendMode highQuality:(BOOL) yerOrNo;
{
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(70, 70);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0f);
    if (yerOrNo) {
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, true);
        CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, true);
        CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
    }
    [tintColor setFill];
    CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    UIRectFill(bounds);

    [image drawInRect:bounds blendMode:blendMode alpha:1.0f];

    if (blendMode != kCGBlendModeDestinationIn)
        [image drawInRect:bounds blendMode:kCGBlendModeDestinationIn alpha:0.4];

    UIImage *tintedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return tintedImage;
}
```

**Utils.h**

```
- (UIImage *)tintedImageWithColor:(UIImage*)image : (UIColor *)tintColor blendingMode:(CGBlendMode)blendMode highQuality:(BOOL) yerOrNo;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found this piece on code in one of my projects, I don't know the exact source, but it should works, use `kCGBlendModeDestinationIn`:

```
- (UIImage *)tintedImageWithColor:(UIColor *)tintColor blendingMode:(CGBlendMode)blendMode highQuality:(BOOL) yerOrNo;
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, NO, 0.0f);
    if (yerOrNo) {
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, true);
        CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, true);
        CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
    }
    [tintColor setFill];
    CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height);
    UIRectFill(bounds);
    [self drawInRect:bounds blendMode:blendMode alpha:1.0f];

    if (blendMode != kCGBlendModeDestinationIn)
        [self drawInRect:bounds blendMode:kCGBlendModeDestinationIn alpha:1.0];

    UIImage *tintedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return tintedImage;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'm going to have to ask you a very stupid question about this snippet. As it will go in 'util.m', I don't have a self. What should I replace self with? I don't understand the line `[self drawInRect:bounds...` I do have a self, but it does not contain 'drawInRect'.

Comment: It's a legit question. This is supposed to be added as a category on UIImage. So self is the UIImage instance you are sending the tint message, like : [myImage tintedImageWithColor:[UIColor redColor] blendingMode: kCGBlendModeDestinationIn] , thus self is myImage.

Comment: I updated my original post. I tried out the function and I am getting the exact same result: an yellow image with opacity 0.5. If I remove the tint function call, I get the image. So myImage does contain an image. Hmmmmm....

Comment: I'm not getting the effect you'd like to achieve. Could you please post with a color different than yellow, I can't see nothing and the effect you need. I've found the original source of that code, it's a n interesting reading http://robots.thoughtbot.com/designing-for-ios-blending-modes